# How to force Windows Media Foundation h264 encoder to use complete bandwidth in CBR mode

Tags: h.264, video-encoding, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to use Windows Media foundation to encode a video with the h264 codec.
The video should be encoded in constant bit rate mode with a high bitrate. I'm trying to get a video output in very high quality.

If I encode a video, which has a lot of motion in it, the encoded video has the bitrate, which matches the bitrate, which was configured.

If I encode a video, which has almost no motion in it, the encoded videos bitrate is very low and does not change, if I change the bitrate in the encoder.

This wouldn't be an issue if the quality of the encoded video would be good. The encoded video of a static image has noticeable compression artifacts, like color gradients are not being smooth. They get better after a short while.

I tried to encode in FullHD with bitrates between 10 and 100 Mbit. The size of the encoded video of a static image (<5 sec) were around 3MB and had always similar artifacts.

I tried the following:

```
    MFCreateMediaType(&_input_type);
    MFCreateMediaType(&_output_type);

    _output_type->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    _output_type->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
    _output_type->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, m_bit_rate);
    _output_type->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);

    MFSetAttributeSize(_output_type, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, m_width, m_height);
    MFSetAttributeRatio(_output_type, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, static_cast<uint32_t>(m_sample_rate), 1);
    MFSetAttributeRatio(_output_type, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);



    auto hr = m_SinkWriter->AddStream(_output_type, &_stream_index);

    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    _input_type->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    _input_type->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32);
    _input_type->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    MFSetAttributeSize(_input_type, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, m_width, m_height);
    MFSetAttributeRatio(_input_type, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, static_cast<uint32_t>(m_sample_rate), 1);
    MFSetAttributeRatio(_input_type, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);


    hr = m_SinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(_stream_index, _input_type, nullptr);

    ICodecAPI* ca;

    hr = m_SinkWriter->GetServiceForStream(_stream_index, GUID_NULL, __uuidof(ICodecAPI), (void**)&ca);

    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;


    {
         VARIANT v = {};
         v.vt = VT_UI4;
         v.uintVal = eAVEncCommonRateControlMode_CBR;
         ca->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode, &v);
    }

    {
         VARIANT v = {};
         v.vt = VT_UI4;
         v.uintVal = m_bit_rate;
         ca->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncCommonMeanBitRate, &v);
    }
```

Is there anything I can do to force the h264 encoder to use the bitrate, which I configured?
Or can I at least improve the quality of the video and reduce/remove the comression artifacts?